# Input/output error while writing large CSV with dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

I have a large CSV (200 GB) that I have loaded in and processed/manipulated in Dask to be in the correct form that I need.

When executing the following line:

```
df_final.to_csv(
    prefix,
    sep="\t",
    index=False,
    header=False,
    chunksize=5000,
)
```

I am running into the following error (definitely related to writing the CSV and not previous delayed computations). It occurs consistently after writing ~25GB:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 87, in <module>
    dask_convert(directory, filename, prefix)
  File "file.py", line 34, in dask_convert
    df_final.to_csv(prefix, sep="\t", index=False, header=False, chunksize=5000)
  File "/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 1465, in to_csv
    return to_csv(self, filename, **kwargs)
  File "/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/csv.py", line 865, in to_csv
    delayed(values).compute(**compute_kwargs)
  File "/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 283, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
  File "/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 565, in compute
    results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File "/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/threaded.py", line 84, in get
    **kwargs
  File "/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 487, in get_async
    raise_exception(exc, tb)
  File "/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 317, in reraise
    raise exc
  File "/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 222, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)
  File "/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 121, in _execute_task
    return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
  File "/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/utils.py", line 35, in apply
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/csv.py", line 679, in _write_csv
    df.to_csv(f, **kwargs)
  File "/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fsspec/core.py", line 121, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fsspec/core.py", line 149, in close
    _close(self.fobjects, self.mode)
  File "/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fsspec/core.py", line 209, in _close
    f.close()
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

As you can see, I have a smallish chunk size specified. I also have over 500GB memory available so that is not the issue either.

Any ideas on what I can do to resolve the issue would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Don’t specify an argument `chunksize` when writing with [`dask.dataframe.to_csv`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.to_csv.html). `chunksize` is not an argument to this function. However, dask passes all extra arguments to [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), so this arg is being interpreted by pandas. So, you end up with both dask and pandas trying to manage chunks independently.

Instead, just make sure you have the partition sizes you want first, then write to csv using the other arguments. Dask will automatically partition your csv into multiple files.